# cURL to PowerShell - Double hash table in --data?

Tags: powershell, curl

I've been trying (and failing for hours) to convert this cURL script into PowerShell:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://example.net \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1234567890' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "data": {
        "MID": 33,
        "DID": "66666666",
        "CID": 10002,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "HID": "11"
    }
}'
```

My PowerShell script looks like this - I suspect it's something to do with the double hash table I've created in $Body but I am really at a loss.:

.. script snipped for simplicity

```
$Body =   @{
    'data'= @{
      'MID'= 33;
      'DID'= "66666666";
      'CID'=10002;
      'status'="ACTIVE";
      'HID'= "11"
    }
}
$CurlArgument = '-X', 'POST',
                'https://example.net',
                '-H', 'Authorization: Bearer 1234567890',
                '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                '-d', 
                $Body
$CURLEXE = 'C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe'
& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument
```

I get the following error message when it executes:

```
..."message":"Access not allowed","details":{"5011":"A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"}}]}
```

I experimented with adding after $Body:

```
| ConvertTo-Json
```

but that then gives me this error:

```
Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

My $CurlArgument variable looks like this (which looks the same as the first cURL script):

```
-X
POST
https://example.net
-H
Authorization: Bearer 1234567890
-H
Content-Type: application/json
-d
{
    "data":  {
                 "CID":  10002,
                 "MID":  33,
                 "HID":  "11",
                 "DID":  "66666666",
                 "status":  "ACTIVE"
             }
}
```

As always, assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not match your output: a `$Body` variable containing a `[hashtable]` instance would not render as JSON text. That a hashtable doesn't automatically turn into a JSON string is indeed the crux of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your `$Body` variable contains a [*hashtable* (`@{ ... }`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables), so you must explicitly convert it to JSON with `ConvertTo-Json`.
- Additionally, because you're calling an *external program*, you must escape the `"` chars. in the JSON string as `\"`<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
$CurlArgument = '-X', 'POST',
                'https://example.net',
                '-H', 'Authorization: Bearer 1234567890',
                '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                '-d', 
                (($Body | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '"', '\"')
```

---

<sup>[1] This additional escaping requirement is highly unfortunate, but to date it has been kept around for the sake of backward compatibility. 
 [This GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361) tells the whole story.</sup>