# cURL to PowerShell - Hash Table

Tags: json, powershell, curl, hashtable

So, after posting my earlier cURL to PowerShell Hash Table question, (which was solved), I've now run into a further issue converting cURL to PowerShell this time with 3 hash tables in data(?) (or more likely my PowerShell skills). This time, my script via PowerShell returns:

```
...General Error java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Here is the cURL which works perfectly via Postman:

```
curl -X PATCH \
  https://example.com/apis/v1.1/parameters \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1234567890' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "data": [
        {
            "DUID": 3299,
            "AID": 551,
            "CID": 10002,
            "Parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "Customer.1/AddressLine1",
                    "value": "SOMEWHERE ROAD"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```

Here is the PowerShell script, which I constructed using advice given in my earlier question here:

[cURL to PowerShell - Double hash table in --data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423081/curl-to-powershell-double-hash-table-in-data)

```
$CURLEXE = 'C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe'
$URL1 = "https://example.com/apis/v1.1/parameters"

$Body =   @{
      'data'= @{
      'DUID'= 3299;
      'AID'= 551;
      'CID'= 10002;
      'Parameters'=
      @{'name'= "Customer.1/AddressLine1";
        'value'= "SOMEWHERE ROAD"}
                }
            }

$CurlArgument = '-X', 'PATCH',
                $URL1,
                '-H', 
                $AuthBearer,
                '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                '-H', 'cache-control: no-cache',
                '-d', 
                (($Body | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '"', '\"')

& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument
```

My $CurlArgument looks like this:

```
-X
PATCH
https://example.com/apis/v1.1/parameters
-H
Authorization: Bearer 1234567890
-H
Content-Type: application/json
-H
cache-control: no-cache
-d
{
    \"data\":  {
                 \"CID\":  10002,
                 \"DUID\":  3299,
                 \"AID\":  551,
                 \"Parameters\":  {
                                          \"value\":  \"SOMEWHERE ROAD\",
                                          \"name\":  \"Customer.1/AddressLine1\"
                                      }
             }
}
```

Which returns this error:

> {"status":"FAILURE","errors":[{"code":"5004","name":"General Error","severity":"3","message":"Error Occured During the operation","details":{"5004":"General Error java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List"}}]}

Could it be the forward slash in the 'Customer.1/AddressLine1' field? I tried a second -replace with these and still got the same error:

```
(($Body | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '"', '\"' -replace '/', '\/')
(($Body | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '"', '\"' -replace '/', '\2f')
(($Body | ConvertTo-Json) -replace '"', '\"' -replace '/', '\%2f')
```

Could it be the lack of square brackets in data hash table? They are there in cURL but not in PowerShell, however in my previous script I didn't have square brackets, plus PowerShell doesn't seem to like them.

Could it be the order of "value" and "name" being changed by PowerShell?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

***Update***
Thanks to the help so far from @mklement0, I've edited my PowerShell to the following which resolved it!

```
$Body =   @{
      data = , @{
      DUID = 3299
      AID = 551
      CID = 10002
      Parameters = , @{
         name = "Customer.1/AddressLine1"
         value = "SOMEWHERE ROAD"
                             }
                }
            }

$CurlArgument = '-X', 'PATCH',
                'https://example.com/apis/v1.1/parameters',
                '-H', 
                $AuthBearer,
                '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                '-H', 'cache-control: no-cache',
                '-d', 
                (($Body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4) -replace '"', '\"')

& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument
```

Comment: your body in the 1st section has a JSON array in brackets. the 2nd one is NOT an array, from what i understand of JSON - it's a hashtable. that is what you defined in the PoSh version with `@{}` instead of with `@()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lee Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) provided the crucial pointer:

**Your JSON format requires an *array* of sub-objects**  (`[...]`) as the value of the `data` and `data.Parameters` properties, whereas the seemingly equivalent hashtables you've constructed in `$Body` have only a single, scalar sub-object.

Two tweaks to your code are required:

- **Ensure that `data` and `data.Parameters` contain *arrays***:

  - Use `, <object>` to construct a single-element array containing `<object>`; `ConvertTo-Json` automatically converts arrays to JSON `[ ... ]` notation.
- Use `-Depth 4` with `ConvertTo-Json` so as to ensure that all sub-objects in the object hierarchy are represented in full.

```
$CURLEXE = 'C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe'
$URL1 = "https://example.com/apis/v1.1/parameters"

$Body = @{
  data = , @{ # Note the "," to construct an *array*
    DUID = 3299
    AID = 551
    CID = 10002
    Parameters = , @{ # Note the "," to construct an *array*
       name = "Customer.1/AddressLine1"
       value = "SOMEWHERE ROAD"
    }
  }
}

# Note the -Depth 4 in the ConvertTo-Json call.
$CurlArgument = '-X', 'PATCH',
                $URL1,
                '-H', 
                $AuthBearer,
                '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                '-H', 'cache-control: no-cache',
                '-d', 
                (($Body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4) -replace '"', '\"')


& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument
```

Comment: Thank you SO much @mklement0 - I had one missing comma after my URL which meant my $AuthBearer wasn't being sent, however your suggested amendments above fixed my problem!

Out of interest, where is all this documented so I can do some reading/learning?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Simon. PowerShell has help topics not just for specific cmdlets (e.g., `Get-Help ConvertTo-Json`), but also about a variety of conceptual topics: `Get-Help about_Hash_Tables`, `Get-Help about_Splatting`. While there is `Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`, it doesn't cover the additional requirements for calling _external programs_; you can learn about them [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361).