# cURL to PowerShell - Hash Table with multiple items

Tags: powershell, curl

OK, I am struggling again with a cURL to PowerShell conversion, specifically in my hash table structure. This time the hash table has multiple items in the Parameter table:

This is the cURL from Postman, which works correctly:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://example.net \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1234567890' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "data": [
        {
            "DUID": 3299,
            "AID": 551,
            "CID": 10002,
            "Parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "Customer.*/Address1",
                    "value": "Street 1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Customer.*/Address2",
                    "value": "Street 2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Customer.*/City",
                    "value": "Somewhere"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Customer.*/State",
                    "value": "NSW"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Customer.*/PostCode",
                    "value": "1234"
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```

I've tried many different attempts using examples from this post:

[cURL to PowerShell - Double hash table in --data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423081/curl-to-powershell-double-hash-table-in-data)

This is my current script, but PowerShell doesn't like the closing curly brace, the comma then the opening curly brace between the items in the Parameter table:

```
$URL1 = "https://example.net"
$Body = @{ 
        data = , @{
            DUID= 3299
            AID= 551
            CID= 10002
            Parameters = @{
                    name  = "Customer.*/Address1"
                    value = "Street 1"
                },
                {
                    name  = "Customer.*/Address2"
                    value = "Street 2"
                },
                {
                    name  = "Customer.*/City"
                    value = "Somewhere"
                },
                {
                    name  = "Customer.*/State"
                    value = "NSW"
                },
                {
                    name  = "Customer.*/PostCode"
                    value = "2345"
                }}}

$CurlArgument = '-s', '-X', 'POST',
                '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                $URL1,
                '-H', 
                $AuthBearer,
                '-d', 
                ($Body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4) -replace '"', '\"'

Write-Host "Command took" (Measure-Command {& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument}).TotalSeconds "Seconds" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

I've tried taking the extra braces out, adding a @ before the braces, taking the commas out but the hash table isn't correctly formatted and my cURL request fails. Due to limitations, I can't PATCH the Parameters once they're added, so I have to send the above in one command.

Any help (again) would be greatly appreciated. I have tried to google and read up about hash tables but I couldn't fond any assistance.

When I currently look at my $CurlArgument, it looks like this (which is wrong):

```
{
    \"data\":  [
                 {
                     \"CID\":  10002,
                     \"DUID\":  3299,
                     \"AID\":  551,
                     \"Parameters\":  [
                                              {
                                                  \"value\":  \"Street 1\",
                                                  \"name\":  \"Customer.*/Address1\"
                                              },
                                              {
                                                  \"Attributes\":  \"\",
                                                  \"File\":  null,
                                                  \"IsFilter\":  false,
                                                  \"IsConfiguration\":  false,
                                                  \"Module\":  null,
                                                  \"StartPosition\":  \"System.Management.Automation.PSToken\",
                                                  \"DebuggerHidden\":  false,
                                                  \"Id\":  \"1234567890\",
                                                  \"Ast\":  \"{\r\n                    name  = \\"Customer.*/Address2\\"\r\n                    value = \\"Street 1\\"\r\n                }\"
                                              },
```

...snip

**Answer**
Thanks to Mike Twc, I edited my script and it worked

```
$URL1 = "https://example.net"
$Body =    @{ 
        data = , @{
            DUID= 3299
            AID= 551
            CID= 10002
            Parameters = @{
                    name  = "Customer.*/Address1"
                    value = "Street 1"
                },
                @{
                    name  = "Customer.*/Address2"
                    value = "Street 2"
                },
                @{
                    name  = "Customer.*/City"
                    value = "Somewhere"
                },
                @{
                    name  = "Customer.*/State"
                    value = "NSW"
                },
                @{
                    name  = "Customer.*/PostCode"
                    value = "2345"
                }}}

$CurlArgument = '-s', '-X', 'POST',
                '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                $URL1,
                '-H', 
                $AuthBearer,
                '-d', 
                ($Body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4) -replace '"', '\"'

Write-Host "Command took" (Measure-Command {& $CURLEXE @CurlArgument}).TotalSeconds "Seconds" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Comment: You already have json, why do you need  hashtables? Any reason for  using curl instead of iwr or webclient?

Comment: I need to "translate" the cURL into my PowerShell script. To do that, you need to re-format the cURL into a PowerShell friendly version of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hashtable is broken, "Parameters" is an array of scriptblocks (you missed @).
Anyway, I see no point using curl, why not just:

```
$url = "https://example.net"
$headers = @{'Authorization: Bearer'='1234567890'; 'Content-Type'='application/json'}
$body = '{your json here}'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

Regarding broken hashtable, this works fine on my end:

```
$Body =  @{ 
    data =  @{
        DUID = 3299
        AID = 551
        CID = 10002
        Parameters =  

            @{  name  = "Customer.*/Address1"
                value = "Street 1"},

            @{
                name  = "Customer.*/Address2"
                value = "Street 2"
            },

            @{
                name  = "Customer.*/City"
                value = "Somewhere"
            },

            @{
                name  = "Customer.*/State"
                value = "NSW"
            },
            @{
                name  = "Customer.*/PostCode"
                value = "2345"
            }
        }
    }


    $Body | convertto-json -Depth 4
```